# Showing and hiding rows not working

Tags: jquery

Alright, check this out.  Why is this not working?

```
<table>
    <tr data-email='some1@some.com'>
        <td>some1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr data-email='some2@some.com'>
        <td>some2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr data-email='some3@some.com'>
        <td>some3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr data-email='some4@some.com'>
        <td>some4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr data-email='some1@any.com'>
        <td>any1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr data-email='some2@any.com'>
        <td>any2</td>
    </tr>
</table>
<input type='checkbox' name='toggle' class='toggle' value='1' checked>
```

and my JS:

```
$(".toggle").click(function () {
    if ($(this).attr("checked") == true) {
        $("tr[data-email=*'@some.com']").show();
    } else {
        $("tr[data-email=*'@some.com']").hide();
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/xt4qC/

Looking to toggle the table rows based off a custom attribute and it seems to ignore it?  How come?  Everything seems like it is coded correctly? Or am I missing something that I am overlooking.

Comment: It's `*=`, not `=*`.  http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/

Comment: Oh man! I knew I was looking at it too long! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First the selector is wrong. It should be `*=` not `=*`. Secondly, use `is(':checked')` instead of reading the `checked` attribute. Try this:

```
$(".toggle").click(function () {
    if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
        $("tr[data-email*='@some.com']").show();
    } else {
        $("tr[data-email*='@some.com']").hide();
    }
});
```

[**Updated fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/xt4qC/5/)

You can also shorten the logic:

```
$(".toggle").click(function () {
    $('tr[data-email*="@some.com"]')[$(this).is(":checked") ? 'show' : 'hide']();
});
```

Comment: I'd suggest `$('tr[data-email*="@some.com"]').toggle($(this).is(":checked"))` :-)

Comment: @RocketHazmat that too :D

Comment: Thanks for the thorough answer.  I definitely had the * out of place and thanks for the is().  I sometimes forget to use what is available like the is() function.  Much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [contains selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/) like this  *=

So change

```
 $("tr[data-email=*'@some.com']").hide();
 //              ^^
```

to

```
 $("tr[data-email*='@some.com']").hide();
```

Also another problem that RoryMcCrossan pointed out the if statement is incorrect

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/xt4qC/4/)